# Get user attributes using user_id - Rails w/ React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

[EDIT]  I am using the React and Rails differently and not using the react-rails gem...

Ok so i have my api written in Rails and it is formatted like this:

```js
data: {
  comments: [
    {
      comment: 'Lorem Ipsum',
      user_id: 1
    },
    {
      comment: 'dolor sit',
      user_id: 2
    },
    {
      comment: 'amet',
      user_id: 3
    } 
  ]
}
```

now, in my react view, i want to have somewhat like, `<%= User.find_by_id(params[:id]).name %>`. What am I thinking is just to add `posted_by` attribute to table and add it as a key in api, having the string value of the `user_id` already set up with the controller(rails approach) and another one is to write another request(react approach) that will just fetch the name but i think its too much. What is the better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this might be late. I just added a relationship between user and comments and added `posted_by: Comment.user.name` in the json response

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it really depends on the numbers. You don't want to make, say, 15 requests if you have 15 comments on that page. My general proposing  would be to keep this as close to [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) as possible. However, if you want to stick to your current case, I would have two datasets:

1.Comments - which would be something like you have already
2.Users - Array of users, with all required fields (like name).

So that you would do only two requests initially.